# Wpf reading file blocks UI thread when using async withn task

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I have a command that reads files and puts them in rich text block, but I came up with a problem - that command is blocking UI thread.

So code looks like:

```
    public ICommand ShowDataCommand => new Command(async log =>
    {
        var selectedItem = (ProcessedRawEventData)log;
        if (selectedItem == null) return;

        this.IsDataDisplayVisible = false; //Hides text block
        this.IsDataDisplayProgressRingVisible = !this.IsDataDisplayProgressRingVisible; // Show progress ring
        this.DataDisplay = await Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllText(selectedItem.LogFile.FullName)); //block
        this.IsDataDisplayProgressRingVisible = false; // Hide progress ring
        this.IsDataDisplayVisible = !this.IsDataDisplayProgressRingVisible; // Show text box
    });
```

And my xaml block is simple:

```
<StackPanel>

    <mah:ProgressRing  Width="5" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                       IsActive="{Binding IsDataDisplayProgressRingVisible}" 
                       Foreground="{DynamicResource AccentBaseColorBrush}" />

    <ScrollViewer Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="#424242" Width="800" MaxHeight="635" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  Visibility="{Binding IsDataDisplayVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}" >
        <RichTextBox Margin="10">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="{Binding DataDisplay}"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
    </ScrollViewer>

</StackPanel>
```

I checked, when Replace reading file procedure with:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```

UI thread does not block, what am I missing?

Comment: Could it be that the read is quick, but updating the RichTextBox takes a lot of time?

For IO-bound work like this it is also usually better to use File.ReadAllTextAsync instead of a worker thread.

Comment: Not possible to provide a good answer without a [mcve]. However, @Magnus is almost certainly correct. The `Task.Run()` method isn't going to block at all; there's no way that the UI thread is being held up by that, nor the `await`. So it's something else in that method, and the most likely candidate is the part that copies the file content into the control itself. You need a different strategy for updating the UI if you don't like that delay, because it's unavoidable using the approach you've got here.

Comment: Aye after deeper research I noticed that text binding is something that slows down UI if Ill solve this I will post it.

Comment: Yes, in my limited experience with WPF's RichTextBox it can be very slow. May not relate to your case, but in a project where we had files in RTF-format, including images, it could take a minute just to show the file (probably the conversion to FlowDocument). We are using the WinForms RichEditBox embedded with WindowsFormsHost instead, with stellar performance for RTF.

Answer (score -1):

Try to call ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid forcing the callback to be invoked on the original context (UI Thread):

```
this.DataDisplay = await Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllText(selectedItem.LogFile.FullName)).ConfigureAwait(false)
```

Comment: Often a good idea, but the RichTextBox must be updated on the UI-thread so it wouldn't help in this case. It wouldn't crash since it is the source target of a binding that is updated, so the call would be marshaled back to the UI-thread.